# What is the correct way to use prepareForReuse?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, prepareforreuse

Need help with understanding how to use prepareForReuse() in UIKit.
The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) says

> you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to
>   content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state

but what about resetting individual property attributes such as isHidden?

Assuming my cell has 2 labels where should I reset:

1. label.text
2. label.numberOfLines
3. label.isHidden

My  tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) delegate has conditional logic to hide/show labels per cell.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

tldr: use `prepareForReuse` to cancel out existing network calls that can can finish after downloading a different indexPath. For all other intents and purposes just use `cellForRow(at:`. This slightly against Apple docs. But that's how most devs do stuff. It's inconvenient to have cell configuration logic at both places...

---

Apple docs say use it to reset attributes *not* related to *content*. However based on experience it might easier to do just do everything inside `cellForRow` for content and not. The only time that it actually makes sense is to

Quoting from [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) for `prepareForReuse`:

> For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell
> that are **not related to content**, for example, alpha, editing, and
> selection state.

e.g. if a cell was selected, you just set it to unselected, if you changed the background color to something then you just reset it back to its *default* color.

> The table view's delegate in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` **should
> always reset all content** when reusing a cell.

This means if you were trying to set the profile images of your contact list you shouldn't attempt to `nil` images in `prepareforreuse`, you should correctly set your images in the `cellForRowAt` and if you didn't find any image **then** you set its image to `nil` or a default image. Basically the `cellForRowAt` should govern both the expected/unexpected status.

So basically the following is **not** suggested:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    imageView?.image = nil
}
```

instead the following is recommended:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

     cell.imageView?.image = image ?? defaultImage // unexpected situation is also handled. 
     // We could also avoid coalescing the `nil` and just let it stay `nil`
     cell.label = yourText
     cell.numberOfLines = yourDesiredNumberOfLines

    return cell
}
```

Additionally default non-content related items as below is recommended:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    isHidden = false
    isSelected = false
    isHighlighted = false
    // Remove Subviews Or Layers That Were Added Just For This Cell

}
```

This way you can safely assume when running `cellForRowAt` then each cell's layout is intact and you just have to worry about the content.

This is the Apple's suggested way. But to be honest, I still think it's easier to dump everything inside `cellForRowAt` just like Matt said. Clean code is important, but this may not really help you achieve that. But as [Connor said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773208/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-prepareforreuse/47514477#comment81985130_40773421) the only time it's necessary is, if you need to cancel an image that is loading. For more see [here](https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e)

ie do something like:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    
    imageView.cancelImageRequest() // this should send a message to your download handler and have it cancelled.
    imageView.image = nil
}
```

---

Additionally in the special case of using RxSwift:
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648830/rxswift-textfield-variable-binding-in-tableview/41675651#41675651) or [here](https://medium.com/gett-engineering/disposing-rxswifts-memory-leaks-6ceb73162170)

Comment: But what if you add a variable number views to a cell's `contentView` based on a data property of a cell? Don't these view need to be removed to properly reset the cell's content? In my specific context, this is more relevant to collection views.

Comment: Will you be (re)setting that variable number for every cell?

Comment: Yes, the data property is an optional that I set to `nil` in `prepareForResue` and only add views if the property is not `nil`.

Comment: you don't need to do that in `prepareForCell`, just in your `cellForRow` for every cell either set the number to a number or just set it to `nil`. If you don't set it to `nil` then the cell would just use the last number that was placed in it

Comment: @Mox what you really need to understand is that a cell doesn't go out of memory as soon as the cell is scrolled out of the screen. It just gets re-used. The cell goes out of memory when either you do something that reduces the number of visible cells on the screen or just deallocate the table view...

Comment: what is this method removeSubviewsOrLayersThatWereAddedJustForThisCell?

Comment: @Saranjith I just named that function as such to communicated to readers that you'd only attempt to get layout back to its original state. Nothing more

Comment: maybe use tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath: to cancel the network calls when that cell has disappeared from the screen?

Answer (score -6):

As stated by the documentation you only have to use the said method to reset attributes that are not related to the content. As for reseting the text/number of lines.... of your labels you could do it from within tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) just before you set their new value, like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    cell.label.text = "" //reseting the text
    cell.label.text = "New value"
    return cell
    }
```

OR

you could take a more object oriented approach and create a subclass of UITableViewCell and define a method say configureCell() to deal with all the resetting and value setting of newly dequeued cells.

Comment: You don't need to reset the text before setting the new value. As long as you populate all labels and set all UI states in `cellForRowAt`, there is no need to "reset" simple properties. See the other answers to this question.