# RxSwift - Textfield-Variable binding in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm new to RxSwift and I have this code to setup a tableview which contains a textfield:

```
budget.expenses.asObservable()
  .bindTo(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: ExpenseInputCell.cellIdentifier, cellType: ExpenseInputCell.self)){(row, element, cell) in

  cell.name.text = element.name.value
  cell.name.rx.text
    .bindTo(element.name)
    .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
}
.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

tableView.rx.itemDeleted
  .subscribe(onNext: {indexPath in
    self.budget.expenses.value.remove(at: indexPath.row)
  })
  .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Everything works fine until a row is deleted, because then the binding of the textfield to the correct object in the array is mixed up. For example lets say I have 7 items in the tableview and I delete the 5th row, the new 5th and 6th row both have the same value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem lies in the lifecycle of the subscription to `element.name`. Because it is tied to `self.disposeBag`, it will not be dismissed when the cell is reused, but when `self` is.

You probably want to expose a new dispose bag on `ExpenseInputCell` and renew it in cell's `prepareForReuse` method.

```
class ExpenseInputCell: UITableViewCell {
  // ..

  var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

  override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.diposeBag = DisposeBag()
  }
}
```

and in view controller

```
budget.expenses.asObservable()
  .bindTo(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: ExpenseInputCell.cellIdentifier, cellType: ExpenseInputCell.self)){(row, element, cell) in

  cell.name.text = element.name.value
  cell.name.rx.text
    .bindTo(element.name)
    .addDisposableTo(cell.disposeBag)
}
.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```