# Swift iOS -How to clean up a Cell's Class Properties and an ImageView's Image (also inside the cell)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, properties, prepareforreuse

I use CollectionViewCells and a TableViewCells inside my app but for this example, I'm just going to list the TableViewCell info because they both use `prepareForReuse`.

Inside the cell I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundViewForPlayerLayer: UIView!

var data: MyData?
var currentTime: CMTime? // used to keep track of the current play time when the app is sent to the background

var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
var player: AVPlayer?
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
```

When I get the table data for my cell I feed the data to the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I pass it to a `data` property inside the cell and I set the cell's thumbnail image and title outlet's in `awakeFromNib()`. I understand how cells are scrolled off the scene and then reused so I use `prepareForReuse` to clean the cell up.

[Here Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse):

> For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell
>   that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and
>   selection state. The table view's delegate in
>   tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) should always reset all content when
>   reusing a cell.

When it's time to clean up the cell in `prepareForReuse` I've found out through trial and error the best way to clean up a label's text is to use `label.text = ""` instead of `label.text = nil` and apparently from the above Apple doesn't want `prepareToReuse` to be used for more than light clean up. However, I've read other posts on SO that it's best to clean up and remove the AVPlayerLayer by setting it to `nil` and removing it from its super layer in `prepareForReuse`.

I have 2 questions

1. If not inside `prepareForReuse` then where do I reset the `currentTime` and `data` properties to `nil` and the `imageView's image` to `nil`? This is assuming the app was sent to the background and `currentTime` property was set to some value.
2. If I cannot set a label's text to nil in `prepareForReuse` then why is it best to set the AVPlayerLayer to nil in `prepareForReuse`?

The TableVIewCell:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView!

var data: MyData?
var currentTime: CMTime?
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
var player: AVPlayer?
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?

override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appHasEnteredBackground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)

        titleLabel.text = data.title!
        thumbnailImageView.image = data.convertedUrlToImage() // url was converted to an image

        configureAVPlayer() //AVPlayer is configured
}


override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        titleLabel.text = ""

        player?.pause()
        playerLayer?.player = nil
        playerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

        // should I reset these 3 here or somewhere else?
        data = nil
        currentTime = nil
        thumbnailImageView.image = nil
}

@objc func appHasEnteredBackground() {

        currentTime = player.currentTime()
        // pause the player...
}

}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        let data = tableData[indexPath.row]

        cell.data = data

        return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: [prepareForReuse clean up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774858/4833705)

Seems the best way to clean up the cell is to do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath before setting the content.