# Why we use super.prepareForReuse when using prepareForReuse of Custom cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Because I already read [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) of Apple and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773208/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-prepareforreuse/47514477) I understand why we use prepareForReuse method.

However I don't understand why we add super.prepareForReuse() to prepareForReuse().

I guess it is very basic knowledge about Swift, so i did google hard. But I can't understand about that. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: because Apple says so. The documentation says:

> If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass implementation

That means call `super`. Just do it. Clearly the UITableViewCell class *itself* does something in its implementation of `prepareForReuse`, and Apple is telling you to make sure it gets to do that.

That's all there is to say about the matter, because Cocoa is closed source. You cannot see *what* UITableViewCell does. And you shouldn't care. Just do what Apple tells you. That is how to use the Cocoa framework.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: No problem. This is just the price we pay for using a closed framework. You just have to pay attention to the docs, because they are the only way of knowing what the rules are. You might be able to deduce by experimentation what can go wrong if you fail to call `super`, but then again you might not, and it's really not worth the effort.